# ssh to TV and control dvd iso play

Tags: ssh, iso, dvd, cvlc

I would like SSH to a computer with a TV as its monitor and remotely control
dvd.iso playing on the TV screen from the command line.
Can I?

Comment: https://wiki.videolan.org/Console/#:~:text=The%20rc%20module%20is%20a,no%20GUI%20environment%20is%20available.